# Biology and Physics are to ‘the sciences’ as Fine Art and Theatre Studies are to what?

Tags: terminology, fine-performing-arts, liberal-arts

I am editing something and am trying to find an alternative to the phrase ‘the sciences and the creative subjects’, as the use of the latter implies that the former are not creative.

For context, we are discussing those university courses that will be hardest-hit by post-coronavirus social distancing/remote teaching measures due to their reliance on equipment and lab/workshop space.

Is there a generally-accepted term that we could use in place of ‘creative subjects’, meaning subjects like Fine Art and Theatre Studies?

- ‘Humanities’ is too broad;
- ‘Liberal arts’ includes most sciences;
- ‘Performing arts’ doesn't, to my mind, include Fine Art;
- ‘Artistic subjects’ maybe?; or
- ‘the arts’?; or
- ‘Facilities-intensive subjects’ is another possibility, but loses the artistic connection.

---

Per my sixth suggestion and [Cell](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/114394/cell)'s comment, we ended up going for ‘the arts’.

Comment: To answer this question, we need to know what aspects of the "humanities" you wish to exclude.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 'facilities - intensive' as making the distinction (given that you've chosen lab sciences). 'The arts' seems like a reasonable choice, no??

Comment: Maybe _culture_

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I want to exclude those humanities that do not require workshop space (fine art) or students' physical presence (theatre studies)

Comment: Engineering courses need workshop space and, in fact a lot of expensive equipment...

Comment: @Rumps You need to edit your question.  I doubt there is a word for that.  Poetry and sculpture are both fine arts, but only one uses a literal workshop.

Comment: Googling [music + art + departments + college](https://www.google.com/search?q=music+art+departments+college) in the hopes of getting various combined descriptions (this is the reason for including "college") might lead you to some ideas. For example, there is [Visual Arts and Music](http://www.ccis.edu/departments/visualartsandmusic.aspx) that might work, and if not, might be tweaked to work.

Comment: If you wrote "the arts" I would imagine those disciplines you listed.

Comment: "Fine arts" encompasses all of these. What you seem to mean by "fine arts" in your list are studio arts (painting, sculpture, etc.) but the performing arts (music, theater) are also fine arts. So "fine arts" includes "performing arts," not the other way around.

Comment: @Damila Interesting, although within the context of our university at least Fine Art is the name of a specific Bachelor's degree scheme.

Comment: Understood, but can a student get a BFA in music? theater?

Comment: @Damila At my (UK) university at least, you get a ‘Bachelor's of Art (BA)’ in all of those subjects (e.g., BA in Theatre Studies, BA in Fine Art, BA in Music), as opposed to a ‘Bachelor's of Science (BSc)’.

Comment: Ahhh. Maybe it's a UK vs US thing, or University specific. Cheers.